# Firebase Storage: How to store image url as an object property?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image to firebase storage and retrieving its downloadURL. I have created a ADS node in firebase database and a newAd object in its node. 
What i want is that the downloadURL of that image is saved in newAd.picLink i.e property of newAd(Object).

```
addSubmitted.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const newAds = _db.ref("ADS").push();
  const newAd = {};

  const ref = firebase.storage().ref();
  const file = $("#exampleInputFile").get(0).files[0];
  const name = +new Date() + "-" + file.name;
  const task = ref.child(name).put(file, { contentType: file.type });

  task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
    console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
    newAd.picLink = downloadURL; /*this isn't working how can i set 
    downloadURL as newAd objects property*/
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not writing anything to the database after the file has been uploaded. The simplest fix is to update `newAds` in there:

```
task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
  console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
  newAdS.update({ picLink: downloadURL });
});
```